# AWS - Cross region SSL Certificate for the same Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I am facing issue with SSL certificate that I need to bind it to an ELB instance.

Here is the situation:

I have registered a wildcard SSL Certificate in **Region A** for ***.example.com** and **example.com** domain.

There is an ELB instance pointing to **admin.example.com** in region A which has a 443 listener to that SSL cert for HTTPS access and it's working fine.

Now, in **Region B**, I have another new ELB instance that I need to point to the SAME domain with different sub domain. **store.example.com**

To achieve this, I have created a new SSL Cert in the second region and assigned it to that ELB. However,I am keep seeing the "**Not Secure**" warning by the browser when I try to open **store.example.com**

Comment: There is no such thing as an SSL certificate that was valid for a specific “region” only to begin with.

Comment: But when I want to add a listener to an ELB on second region, I can only select certificates that was created on that region only.

Comment: That is something about how Amazon structured their interface then, but it has nothing to do with certificates and how they work itself. So yes, if you can import your existing certificate in that context that should work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do by the way AWS structures their infrastructure.

The only way is to create a new one in the other region.

Comment: I have created a new set of cert for the same domain on the second region, but I am keep getting the "Connection is not Secure" error in my browser when calling the domain, or the ELB.

Comment: If the certificate was generated by the ACM service it can't be exported, so in that situation the only option would be to create a new one in the new region.

Comment: @Benjamin did you assign the new certificate to the load balancer? Is the DNS record actually pointing to the load balancer?

Comment: @MarkB, I have assign the newly created SSL Cert (In the Second Region) to the ELB through Listener option in ELB settings. I have created a new A record in the domain panel to point to the ELB address (with https:// in front). By the way, you are right, I can't seem to be able to export the SSL Cert and import it to that region.

Comment: Why is the connection not secure, what is the error?

Comment: @Benjamin I asked 2 questions, you answered one of them. So again: Is the DNS record actually pointing to the load balancer?

Comment: @MarkB, earlier I wrote in my comment that " *I have created a new A record in the domain panel to point to the ELB address (with https:// in front).* " Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: You don't put "https://" in a domain record, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @MarkB, My apology for giving wrong info. Since the load balancer is going to be used on a subdomain, what I have done is, I have created a sub-domain in the Domain Control panel, and added a "Forward" record for that sub-domain to "https://my-ELB-address". I have not created any CNAME record that points to the load balancer.

Comment: First close all your browser windows and reboot your desktop. I have seen so many issues lately with SSL caching .... What browser are you using? In Chrome for example, click on the not secure button next to your website url path. This will show you the certificate and the error. What does your browser show for "Issued To"?. Does it match store.example.com? Another item, if store.example.com use to point somewhere else you might have to wait for the DNS TTL to expire. In that case use a different system to test with that has not been to store.example.com.